# The 'or' in the search

Tags: feature-request, search, tag-search

By accident, I discovered that if I search for two tags, and put an `or` between them, the search lists all questions which contain at least one of the given tags. Before, I only had the option to click the tags I was searching for, and got only the question which had all the marked tags.

Why is this `or` operator so hidden? I mean, I found no info about it anywhere on the site. Wouldn't it be great to have a button for it? For me, this is really helpful, because sometimes questions just do not have all the tags that I would expect.

**Here is an example:**

1. Question - Tags: Java
2. Question - Tags: Java, Android
3. Question - Tags: Android

*A search for `[Java][Android]` gives me only Question 2.*

*A search for `[Java] or [Android]` gives me all three Questions.*

Comment: I couldn't find it on http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching but it is described on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5229/how-do-i-search-for-questions-with-specific-tags

Comment: Ok, at least it is somewhere. But tbh, I think this is really quite hidden.

Comment: Ok, fine: http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching - it's documented there now. I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for here though; what would you want/need a button for?

Comment: I mean you can click the tags you want to search for. If there would be an option like 'and' & 'or', you would see far easier that there is a possibility to customize the search.

Comment: @Shog9: For cases where there are tags for `foo`, `OrangeFoo`, and `PurpleFoo`, some users will be interested only in `Foo` that are not orange or purple, while others will be interested in all colors of `Foo`, I wonder if there would be value in allowing certain combinations of tags to be marked as "interesting", such that the "related tags" area for a message tagged `foo` would include a button for `[foo|orangeFoo|purpleFoo]`?  In some cases, the way to resolve the "problem" of `orangeFoo`-tagged messages not showing up under `foo` would be to merge the tags, but...

Comment: ...sometimes there can be value in having the tags separate.  I'm not sure what the best way would be to define such "tag groups", but I don't think it would need to be overly complicated.